# Account Object BillingAddress

Tags: api, address, compound-fields

I am creating an Account object and am having trouble associating an Address record to the Billing Address.

This is working for creating an address of billing type:

```
sc_address = sf_client.create!('Address__c',
  Street__c: '24 Willie Mays Plaza',
  City__c: 'San Francisco',
  State__c: 'California',
  ZipPostalCode__c: '94017',
  GeoLocation__Latitude__s: '37.778577',
  GeoLocation__Longitude__s: '-122.389271',
  Type__c: 'Billing',
  SubCustomer__c: '####'
)
```

Adding each address component individually has been working:

```
update_subcust = sf_client.update!('Account', 
  Id: '####', 
  BillingStreet: '24 Willie Mays Plaza', 
  BillingCity: 'San Francisco',
  BillingState: 'California',
  BillingPostalCode: '94017',
  BillingLatitude: '37.778577',
  BillingLongitude: '-122.389271'
)
```

I would like to be able to add this address to the Subcustomer object with something like this, where sc_address is the address created in the first code snippet:

```
update_subcust = sf_client.update!('Account', Id: '0014100000bRYLKAA4', 
  BillingAddress: sc_address
)
```

I get the following error when I attempt it:

```
 JSON_PARSER_ERROR: Cannot deserialize instance of BillingAddress from VALUE_STRING value #### or request may be missing a required field
```

Can anyone let me know if what I am trying to do is possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no, what you're trying to do is not possible.

The longer answer is that the `BillingAddress` field is a 'compound' field (introduced in API v30.0, aka the Spring '14 release), which has a bunch of limitations which are outlined [in the documentation on compound fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_limitations.htm). One of those limitations is that compound fields are read-only. If you want to set values for an address, you need to set values for the individual fields (e.g. `BillingStreet`, `BillingCity`, `BillingPostalCode`, etc...)

Personally, I've attempted to use compound fields in the past, but found it to be more trouble than it was worth.